# MSMQ support for .net core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, msmq, .net-standard-2.0

It looks like there are no libraries provided in .net standard / .net core to support MSMQ.
In that case, how can we use MSMQ while working with asp.net core 2.0 and above web application?

Answer (score 1):

I recently noticed this NUGET package:  Experimental.System.Messaging

I've not yet tried it but it seems like it might be helpful for what you need.